# How to get pre-set fields into a table?

Tags: tables

I'm trying - with no success so far- to develop some code that allows me to call a command (that prints a specific table), with a few of the fields "pre-filled" as they are used as commands in alot of places in the text.

As an example,

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}

\newcommand{\MaterialNamei}{Acrylonitrile butadiene styrene}
\newcommand{\MaterialCodei}{ABS}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMini}{-20}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMaxi}{80}

\newcommand{\MaterialNameii}{Thermoplastic Polyurethane}
\newcommand{\MaterialCodeii}{TPU}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMinii}{-50}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMaxii}{80}

\newcommand{\MaterialNameiii}{Polylactic acid}
\newcommand{\MaterialCodeiii}{PLA}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMiniii}{-10}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMaxiii}{60}

\newcounter{material}

\newcommand{\matetable}[1] {
\stepcounter{material} 

I can get \romannumeral\thematerial 

and obviously \MaterialNamei

% but here I have an error ... 
\begin{tabular}{| p{2cm} | p{7cm} | } 
\hline
Material Full Name &  \csname \MaterialName\romannumeral\thematerial 
\endcsname \\
\hline
Comments & #1 \\  \hline

\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\matetable{blah} 

\matetable{bluh} 

\end{document}
```

thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In your code you write `\csname \MaterialName\romannumeral\thematerial\endcsname`, this way, `\MaterialName` is evaluated and its replacement is used for the macro-name by `\csname`. You want the behaviour, to use the macro called `\MaterialNamei` which should be used with `\csname MaterailName\romannumeral\thematerial\endcsname`. Therefore:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}

\newcommand{\MaterialNamei}{Acrylonitrile butadiene styrene}
\newcommand{\MaterialCodei}{ABS}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMini}{-20}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMaxi}{80}

\newcommand{\MaterialNameii}{Thermoplastic Polyurethane}
\newcommand{\MaterialCodeii}{TPU}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMinii}{-50}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMaxii}{80}

\newcommand{\MaterialNameiii}{Polylactic acid}
\newcommand{\MaterialCodeiii}{PLA}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMiniii}{-10}
\newcommand{\MaterialTempMaxiii}{60}

\newcounter{material}

\newcommand{\matetable}[1] {
\stepcounter{material} 

I can get \romannumeral\thematerial 

and obviously \MaterialNamei

% but here I have an error ... 
\begin{tabular}{| p{2cm} | p{7cm} | } 
\hline
Material Full Name &  \csname MaterialName\romannumeral\thematerial 
\endcsname \\
\hline
Comments & #1 \\  \hline

\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\matetable{blah} 

\matetable{bluh} 

\end{document}
```

Also I would create shortcuts for using material x:

```
\newcommand*{\MaterialName}[1]{%
    \csname MaterialName\romannumeral#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\MaterialCode}[1]{%
    \csname MaterialCode\romannumeral#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\MaterialTempMin}[1]{%
    \csname MaterialTempMin\romannumeral#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\MaterialTempMax}[1]{%
    \csname MaterialTempMax\romannumeral#1\endcsname}
```

This way `\MaterialName{1}` or `\MaterialName{\thematerial}` invokes the correct command and is easier to use than always type the `\csname`.